# have to put @2x manually in the image path to show images properly on retina devices

Tags: ios, iphone, retina

we have @2x images on the server but we have not put @2x in the image name. Now when these are downloaded on the retina devices they are shown wrongly as if they are 1x.After adding @2x at the end of the image names they are shown properly as expected. Can anyone explain why retina devices require @2x suffix for image url?

Comment: Where are you using the downloaded images ?

Comment: If you are using that image in a UIImageView or setting as a button's background then it shouldn't be a problem whether its @2x or not.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add @2x and @3x images in 'Assets.xcassets' file with some name. For example myImage, myImage@2x and myImage@3x.
in your code you can directly use like this  UIImage(named: "myImage"). It will download proper image respective to your device.

Comment: but my question is not about bundled images...its about downloading images from server at run time...

Comment: for that you need write your own logic.